# Should I need to add the preposition "of" to "I prefer not to be around smoking"?

Tags: prepositions

Should I need to add the preposition "of" to the sentence

> "I prefer not to be around (**of**) smoking"

Comment: Is there a reason you think you *would* need it?  After all, isn't *around* already a preposition?

Comment: When I'm thinking about what you said, I see that you're actually right:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Say, "I prefer not to be around smoking" or "I prefer you not to smoke".